# What does weird notation after type class declaration mean

Tags: haskell, syntax, type-kinds

In `ghci` `:i Functor` gives me:

```
class Functor (f :: * -> *) where
  fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
  ...
```

What does `(f :: * -> *)` mean? It looks as if `f` needs to be a function, but that doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3):

The asterisk `*` is the Haskell symbol for *kinds*, the "types of types".

```
Prelude> :k Int
Int :: *
Prelude> :k Maybe
Maybe :: * -> *
Prelude> :k []
[] :: * -> *
Prelude> :k Maybe Int
Maybe Int :: *
```

The `Functor` class is defined for type constructors of kind `* -> *`, which take one type and return a type.